# how to pass data-bind value as parameter when calling breeze function

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I want to pass a data-bind value as function parameter.

Here is sample code:

```
<data-bind="click: function (data) { myFunction('param1', data) }">
```

this is my view model 
 
 var vm = {  
        Category: ko.observableArray(), 
        Product: ko.observableArray(), 
        CatID: ko.observable("113"), 
        save: saveChanges,  
        Filter: FilterProduct, 
        };            
    
                                                       CatID is an observable so there are some functions who change the CatID when they are called. and i want to pass this CatID as a parameter when specific button clicked. 
 
Please help how can i do this.

Comment: please provide more code to explain how you get param1. Is it a user input? is it a user selection value? etc..

Comment: var vm = {
        Category: ko.observableArray(),
        Product: ko.observableArray(),
        Parameter: ko.observable("113"),
        save: saveChanges,
        Filter: FilterProduct,
        };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the observable in the data-bind like this

```
<button data-bind="click: myFunction(CatID)">Test Click</button>
```

And define your function in your ViewModel:

```
var vm = {
        Category: ko.observableArray(),
        Product: ko.observableArray(),
        CatID: ko.observable("113"),
        myFunction: function (obs) {
            alert(obs());
        }
    };
```

I have created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/QruPg/

Comment: Thank You Dear Friend , it works. Currently i do not hold much reputation to mark this as answer ;-). but i promise to come back and ll mark it as helpful answer in future. Thank you again.